# ¿Como habilito/deshabilito elementos de una lista en php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta que hago desde **PHP** a **MYSQL**, a una tabla llamada `temas`, muestro el resultado en forma de lista, en la cual solo debe estar habilitado el primer registro y al ser visualizado debe habilitarse el siguiente y así llevar el orden.

```
if (isset($_GET["ver_temas"])) 
{
    $curso_id = $_GET['ver_temas'];
    //echo $curso_id;
    global $conexion, $curso, $temas, $archivo, $video;
    $sql = "SELECT t.*, a.id visto, a.usuario_id 
            FROM 
            (   SELECT t.* 
                FROM temas t 
                INNER JOIN inscritos cu 
                ON t.curso_id = cu.curso_id 
                WHERE t.curso_id = '$curso_id' 
                AND cu.usuario_id= '$id' ) t 
            LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT * 
                FROM avance 
                WHERE avance.usuario_id = '$id' ) a 
            ON t.id = a.tema_id 
            AND t.curso_id = a.curso_id ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

}
```

Muestro en sentencia `while` el resultado:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>
<ul class="primer-r">
    <li class="temas-lista example_a">
        <img src="../../img/iconos/move-to-next.png" alt="" title="<?php echo $row['tema']; ?>" width="23px">
        <a href="tema.php?tema_view=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="no-visto"><?php echo $row['tema']; ?></a>
    </li><div style="height: 5px; background-color: #EAEFF5"></div>

</ul>
```

Cómo mostrar el primer registro y los demás deshabilitados y cómo llevar el orden? Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Haz intentado usando javascript?

Comment: Como bien dice @Geynen, tendrías que hacerlo en el cliente, vía Javascript, pues desde allí puedes cargar todas las filas, mostrando sólo la primera habilitada y cuando ésta se haya seleccionado la deshabilitas y habilitas la segunda, y así pasas de la 2ª a la 3ª. Puedes incluso poner un `checkbox` al lado de cada fila o algo así.